# Windows phone 8 copy ussd code to dialer

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, ussd

Is there a way I can copy USSD code generated from my app and then open the dialler and then programmatically paste the code to allow the user to press "call"

I've tried using the `PhoneCallTask` class but the phone tells me that it isn't possible to use service codes unless its from the dialler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible. The only way to start a call is using `PhoneCallTask` but that doesn't support service codes as you already found out.